# Simultaneous reading and changing the variable by different threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, thread-synchronization

I am interested in the situation where **one thread is waiting** for change of a variable in the `while` loop:

```
while (myFlag == false) {
    // do smth
}
```

It is repeating an infinite number of times.

In the meantime, **another thread have changed** the value of this variable:

```
myFlag = true;
```

Can the reader-thread see the result of changing the value of the variable in the other thread if this variable is NOT volatile? In general, as I understand it will never happen. Or am I wrong? Then when and under what circumstances, the first thread can see the change in the variable and exit the loop? Is this possible without using `volatile` keyword? Does size of processor's cache play role in this situation?

Please explain and help me understand! Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can the reader-thread see the result of changing the value of the variable in the other thread if this variable is NOT volatile?

It *may* be able to, yes. It's just that it won't *definitely* see the change.

> In general, as I understand it will never happen.

No, that's not the case.

You're writing to a variable and then reading from it in a different thread. Whether or not you see it will depend on the exact processor and memory architecture involved. Without any memory barriers involved, you aren't *guaranteed* to see the new value - but you're certainly not guaranteed *not* to see it either.

Comment: And is this [example](http://invalidcodeexception.com/java-volatile-keyword-by-example) incorrect? Author of the article writes: "When the thread is created, it copies the value of all accessible variables in its own stack. Without volatile keyword the JVM is free to make some optimizations, like never refreshing those local copies in some threads." It follows that the case with an infinite loop execution is possible in this situation. Or is this not so? Thank you!

Comment: @MikeBrown: Yes, an infinite loop is possible. But so is a finite loop. You've taken the *possibility* of an infinite loop as if that were a *guarantee*. Just because a VM is free to make a certain optimization doesn't mean that it *has* to. Your post isn't asking whether the infinite loop is possible - it's asserting that the finite loop *isn't* possible, and that's just not true.

Answer (score 4):

> Can the reader-thread see the result of changing the value of the variable in the other thread if this variable is NOT volatile?

I'd like to expand a bit on @Jon's excellent answer.

The Java memory model says that *all* memory in a particular thread will be updated if it crosses *any* memory barrier.  Read barriers cause all cached memory in a particular thread to be updated from central memory and write barriers cause local thread changes to be written to central.

So if your thread that writes to another `volatile` field or enters a `synchronized` block it will cause your flag to be updated in central memory.  If the reading thread reads from another `volatile` field or enters a `synchronized` block in the `// do smth` section after the update has happened, it will see the update.  You just can't rely on *when* this will happen or if the order of write/read happens appropriately.  If your thread doesn't have other memory synchronization points then it may *never* happen.

**Edit:**

Given the discussion below, which I've had a couple times now in various different questions, I thought I might expand more on my answer.  There is a big difference between the guarantees provided by the Java language and its memory-model and the reality of JVM implementations.  The JLS and JMM define memory-barriers and talk about "happens-before" guarantees only between `volatile` reads and writes on the *same* field and `synchronized` locks on the *same* object.

However, on all architectures that I've heard of, the implementation of the memory barriers that enforce the memory synchronization are *not* field or object specific.  When a read is done on a `volatile` field and the read-barrier is crossed on a specific thread, it will be updated with *all* of central memory, not just the particular `volatile` field in question.  This is the same for `volatile` writes.  After a write is made to a `volatile` field, *all* updates from the local thread are written to central memory, not just the field.  What the  JLS *does* guarantee is that instructions cannot be reordered past the `volatile` access.

So, if thread-A has written to a `volatile` field then all updates, even those *not* marked as `volatile` will have been written to central memory.  After this operation has completed, if thread-B then reads from a different `volatile` field, he will see all of thread-A's updates, even those not marked as `volatile`.  Again, there is *no* guarantees around the timing of these events but if they happen in that order then the two threads will be updated.

Comment: "*The Java memory model says that all memory will be updated if any memory barrier is crossed.*" => I don't think so, even if that is how it is generally implemented.

Comment: I think @assylias Is right. If A happens-before B, and B happens-before C, then A happens-before C. But A has to have a formal happens-before relationship to B -- it's not enough that it happened chronologically before B happened.

Comment: @Gray not really - there is only a hb between a read and a write of the **same** volatile variable. The hb does guarantee that any write before the volatile write will be visible after the volatile read but that's it. So if you write `volatile v1 = 1` and subsequently read `a = volatile v2` it is completely legal for values written before `v1 = 1` not to be visible.

Comment: And even if your read and write is on the same field `v`, it's still possible for some other variable `foo`, which got updated on another thread from the one that wrote to `v`, to not get flushed to all memory everywhere.

Comment: As someone who spent quite some time reading JSR-133 and the Aarch64 spec I can say that as far as I understand the spec assylias is correct. Basically: Everything visible to a thread A when it writes to some volatile field becomes visible to thread B when it reads the volatile field. This does not mean that any other thread is guaranteed to see changes made by thread A if it doesn't read the volatile variable. Assuming obviously we're talking about the new memory model and not the old one, the older one was much laxer on this point.

Comment: There are guarantees and there is reality.  You are all correct in terms of the guarantees of HB.  *However*, the implementation is LoadLoad, StoreStore, or LoadStore (and others).  These operations are _not_ field specific.  If a program calls `LoadLoad`, all memory is loaded -- not just the field in question.  I probably should have have used HB because that confuses the discussion.

Comment: @Gray Better hope you never run into a processor with weak memory model and offering load-acquire/store-release instructions then (fun fact I can think of at least 2).

Comment: _If_ some other field has been updated to central memory by thread B _before_ thread A has read from a `volatile` field, then thread A will see the update even though it is accessing a _different_ volatile field.  Again, there is no guarantees that the timing will happen in that order.

Comment: Then you should edit your answer to the effect of "in common implementations" instead of "The Java memory model says," because the latter is a specific, formal claim that I don't believe is backed by the JMM as specified in the JLS.

Comment: Alpha was always the challenging one to me @Voo.  I'm not at all saying that you can be guaranteed of the timing of these events.

Comment: @Gray Not sure about alpha (weak memory model yes, but I think it only has memory barriers that would affect the whole memory space), IA64 and Aarch64 is what I'm thinking of. The thing is that on those processors you don't get any additional guarantees besides what the JMM says when using load-acquire/store-release.

Comment: @Gray You seem to be misunderstanding me. Under the new JMM when reading from a volatile variable it's guaranteed to see at least the whole state of the thread at the time it wrote to that variable. So for the *reader* this applies to the whole memory, what it doesn't say is that other threads get the same guarantees and load-acquire/store-release don't give you more than exactly these guarantees either.

Comment: @Gray Your statement is factually incorrect. And the implementation is not necessarily a LoadLoad/StoreStore/LoadStore. For example ([cookbook](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html)): "*a volatile field provably accessible from only a single thread acts as a normal field. More fine-grained analyses and optimizations are also possible, for example, those relying on provable inaccessibility from multiple threads only during certain intervals.*" - so technically it is possible that a volatile read/write might not have the effect you describe. And that is perfectly legal according to the JMM.

Comment: Anyway, discussions of the JVM spec or cookbook shouldn't inform discussions of the JLS (including the JMM), as that would be the tail wagging the dog. (You could I suppose make an argument that if X is allowed in the JVM spe, it's probably not disallowed in the JLS, if we assume that the writers of both documents wouldn't make [many] mistakes. But we can't say that something being required in the JVM spec means it's required in the JLS.)

Comment: Find me one definition of memory-barrier that mentions a particular memory segment or address to be updated @assylias.  I've looked and all memory barriers cause full thread state publishing or full cache dumping -- never partial.  I understand that it is allowed by the JMM but it's never implemented that way.  I will update my answer to remove mention of JMM.

Comment: I think we are in agreement @Voo.  What I am trying to say is that if thread-A has published its state to central memory _before_ thread-B updates its state, then all updates from thread-A, even those without a `volatile` keyword, will be seen by thread-B.

Comment: "Then you should edit your answer to the effect of "in common implementations"".  Agreed @yshavit although I would argue that it is _all_ implementations.  But I've removed mention of the JMM.

Comment: @Gray I thought so. Just a misunderstanding after all.

Comment: Yeah, sorry @Voo.  In looking back over your comments, I misread your point.  Guess I was processing too many threads.

Comment: I've updated my answer to make my point more clear and I've mentioned that the JMM does not guarantee this behavior.

Comment: Looking back at my answer, my big miss was in saying "all memory would be updated" when I meant "all memory from a particular thread".  That's where 90% of the confusion came from.  Sorry/thanks.